# Datagridview doesn't change colours when changing combobox values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, colors

I have the following problem with a datagrid.

I have a datagridview with several columns already coloured and a combobox. The first column of my datagridview , "Signal Name" has the same values as the combobox.

My goal is to change the color of the row with the same signal name as in the combobox and leave the others with the same initial colors.

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't "reset" the initial colors when I run it. Instead, the desired row's color is correctly changed but, when I change the value with the combobox to another value, it doesn't reset to the usual colours as it should and I end up with two rows coloured.

```
    Public Sub ComboBox1_Selka() Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged

    dgv_Sigdata.Columns("Target Profit").DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(102, 255, 102)
    dgv_Sigdata.Columns("Avg Loss").DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 197, 141)
    dgv_Sigdata.Columns("Avg Win").DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(102, 255, 102)
    dgv_Sigdata.Columns("Stop Loss").DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 197, 141)
    dgv_Sigdata.Columns("Target Profit").DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_Sigdata.Rows
        If row.Cells.Item(0).Value.ToString = ComboBox1.Text Then


            dgv_Sigdata.Rows(row.Index).Cells("Signal Name").Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(10, 2, 102)
            dgv_Sigdata.Rows(row.Index).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(10, 2, 102)
        Else
            dgv_Sigdata.Rows(row.Index).Cells("Signal Name").Style.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    Next row

  End Sub
```

This code is suppose to reset all columns to their initial colors and then color the combobox row only. Yet, it doesn't.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Put a debug break on the If...Then line and when the code stops, examine the values.  You *probably* want to use ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString instead of ComboBox1.Text.  BTW, you can just use the row variable: `row.Cells("Signal Name").Style.BackColor = Color.White`

Answer (score 0):

First, follow the suggestions made by [LarsTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech).

Next, note the logic of your color changes:

1. You set the default colors for each column. This works.
2. If the first cell value of a row matches the `ComboBox` selection:

   1. Color `Cells("Signal Name")` dark blue. (Redundant to the next line).
   2. Set the default color of that row to dark blue. (Overrides column colors).
3. Else:

   1. Color `Cells("Signal Name")` white. This works.

Once a row's `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` has been set, that takes precedence over the column default.  You could change it back to white, but that still overrides the column colors. The hierarchy seems to work as follows:

```
Cell.Style.BackColor -overrides-> Row.DefaulCellStyle.BackColor -overrides-> Column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
```

Solution:

```
Public Sub ComboBox1_Selka() Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_Sigdata.Rows
        If row.Cells.Item(0).Value.ToString = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString Then
            For Each cell as DataGridViewCell In row
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(10, 2, 102)
            Next cell
        Else
            row.Cells("Target Profit").Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(102, 255, 102)
            row.Cells("Avg Loss").Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 197, 141)
            row.Cells("Avg Win").Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(102, 255, 102)
            row.Cells("Stop Loss").Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 197, 141)
            row.Cells("Target Profit").Style.BackColor = Color.Beige
            row.Cells("Signal Name").Style.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    Next row

End Sub
```

Side note: You're setting `Columns("Target Profit")` twice with separate colors.  I didn't know if that was a simple *oops* or copy-paste error.